# Bytes in different encodings

Tags: java, encoding

It is a very strange question(at least for me), but I've found some strange behavior of encoding in Java.
For example you have some set of bytes. Then you interpret this bytes as string in some encoding. Than you get bytes of this string and save it to some another file.
I think that encoding is just specified way to interpret bytes as string. But in this way bytes must be the same in both files, but they didn't.

This is sample code instance:

```
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("firstFile"));
    byte[] arr = new byte[50000];
    int l = inputStream.read(arr,0,50000);
    arr = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr,0, l);
    BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
    String st = encoder.encode(arr);

    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("secondFile"));
    outputStream.write(st.getBytes(), 0, st.getBytes().length);
    inputStream.close();
    outputStream.close();
```

Comment: There are two encodings 1) your file.encoding system property 2)  String encoding which is based on platform encoding. Also you are writing the base64 encoded string to output file How will the bytes be same.

Comment: Base 64 is a way to encode bytes. You turn an array of bytes into a character representation of those bytes. There is absolutely no reason that a base 64 encoded string of bytes should be anywhere near the string you are encoding. Eg. Take a look at the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) the first example shows exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the first file contains one byte, 0x00.

The Base-64 encoding of that byte will be the `String`, `"AA=="`.

When you call `getBytes()` on that string, you'll get 0x41, 0x41, 0x3D, 0x3D—one byte for each character in the string.

Those are the bytes written to the second file.

Comment: It's exactly what I want, Thank you.